# Where can I find Ad Networks with single liner Ads?

Tags: advertising, web-services, widgets

I've developed a site that serves pure HTML Weather widgets (and they are great looking too). Just after two months I am generating 1.25K hits monthly (Google Analytics). Now I want to generate some money out of it. You can check my service out on [Here](http://www.weatherfor.us) . I am looking for affiliate or an Ads service that can I can hookup within but there is a twist in story. ***I want single liner text Ad in a particular location*** otherwise widgets will look rubbish, see this snapshot:

[image]

Plus I have some unique places in my site to place some banner ads as well, Here are existing set of services that I've already tried:

- Ad Sense, doesn't allow or have such formats of methods.
- Peefly provides you with straight links works best but I recorded some clicks (Through Google Events) and they didn't show me any, plus it introduces overhead of manually going and choosing your links.
- BidVertise totally rubbish opens popups and what not, makes site look like spam

I am new to this ad stuff so have a limited knowledge. Suggestions please? I have one more place in Forecast but I want to start simple. P.S. I also have a MetroUI like widget coming in the pipeline but its not ready yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach to go with, bearing in mind you want a non-standard ad format, and that you don't mind affiliate ads, is to make an ad in the right format that you want for a company that suits the site.   Instead of using the normal link to the homepage, use an affiliate link so that anyone clicking and buying on their website is attributed to you.

Comment: Any site that provides a platform for finding affiliates etc?

Comment: the way affiliate advertising tends to work is a store is partnered with a affiliate network you sign up to a network and then you have access to all their affiliate links. off the top of my head "Rakuten", 'commision junction' and "affiliate window" are some of the most popular

Answer (score 0):

Kontera is the most popular ad network serving text ads and uses words already on your pages http://kontera.com/